# C# Programming How to Tokenize Spacing and "," through Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex, tokenize

I have a C# program which takes in a log string and tries to tokenize it into various arrays.

The string used for the example would be "Tue Oct 26 2010 23:48:54,664,macb,d/drwxrwxrwx,0,0,33-144-1,C:/WINDOWS/system32/ras" which I need both Spacing (' ') and "," to be seperated into arrays. The results from running my programs would be this:

```
Tue Oct 26 2010 23:48:54
664
macb
d/drwxrwxrwx
0
0
33-144-1
C:/WINDOWS/system32/ras
```

This result is only partially right as the "," is being filtered but not the spacing (' '). Therefore I need the time 23:48:54 to be filtered out as well. Can someone please advise me on the codes please? Thanks!

My Codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Testing
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines
          ("C:\\Test\\ntfs2.txt");

        String value = "Tue Oct 26 2010 23:48:54,664,macb,d/drwxrwxrwx,0,0,33-144-
        1,C:/WINDOWS/system32/ras";
        //
        // Split the string on line breaks.
        // ... The return value from Split is a string[] array.
        //

        String rex = @"(\t)|,";

        String[] lines = Regex.Split(value, rex);

        foreach (String line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jens pointed out, you can get away with just using the String.Split method. However, the regular expression will be like this:

```
String rex = @"[\s,]";
```

Comment: @JavaNoob: `\s` means whitespace. `\S` is non-whitespace.

Comment: `\s` is a shorthand for `[ \t\r\n]` which is the set of all whitespace characters (tab, space etc)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
value.Split(new Char[]{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

instead of 
regular expressions.

Comment: Reps up for partial correct answer as I think regular expression would be easier for expansions.